# C, Cygwin, and compiling drand and srand

Tags: c, cygwin, srand

I have a C code which I am trying to compile in Cygwin and which contains both the `drand()` and `srand()` functions.  I had Windows Vista with Cygwin installed and the code seemed to comile fine, but my computer broke and I had to get a new one.  The new computer has Windows 7 64-bit version.  I had a few issues downloading Cygwin but finally managed to do it by only selecting a few packages and then have been trying to get the rest that I need.  The problem is I don't have the help I had installing it on my other computer so I don't know which packages I actually need, so I have just been guessing (all the gcc ones) but I mustn't have the one I need for srand and drand to work.  If anyone could point me in the right direction, and also possibly just let me know which packages I need to compile C so I can check I have them all that would be great.

Thanks a lot in advance for any help.

Sorry, that was a lot of words!

Kaytiana

Answer (score 0):

`srand()` and `drand()` functions are part of the `<stdlib.h>` library and should be included with the gcc-core cygwin package.  If no, then I think it will be an issue with cygwin 64 bit packages or the OS.  Since you mentioned you had problems installing, I am assuming something went wrong on the process.

Answer (score 0):

`drand` is not guaranteed to be part of the C standard library.  That being said, I would install all of the relevant stdlib and gcc libraries first.  I can't imagine a separate drand library existing.